# Jenkins-Plugin: Optional block and its nested radio buttons are not persisted after saving and loading the configuration dialogue

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

I'm trying to get started with Jenkins plugin development and have a little problem regarding the persistence of a global configuration of the plugin.

#### The option in question is an optional block with 2 nested radio buttons, as you can see in the plugin's global.jelly:

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define" xmlns:l="/lib/layout" xmlns:t="/lib/hudson" xmlns:f="/lib/form">

  <f:section title="Hello World Builder">
    <f:optionalBlock name="useForeignLanguage" title="Use foreign language" checked="useForeignLanguage">
      <f:entry title="Language to use" field="useLanguage"
        description="Check if we should say hello in another language">
        <f:radio name="useLanguage" title="French" value="fr" />
        <f:radio name="useLanguage" title="Japanese" value="jp" />
      </f:entry>
    </f:optionalBlock>
  </f:section>

</j:jelly>
```

#### The relevant Java code is as follows:

```
public class HelloWorldBuilder extends Builder {
    //...
    @Extension
    public static final class Descriptor extends BuildStepDescriptor<Builder> {
        private boolean useForeignLanguage;
        private String  useLanguage;

        public Descriptor() {
            load();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean configure( final StaplerRequest req, final JSONObject formData ) throws FormException {
            // To persist global configuration information,
            // set that to properties and call save().
            final JSONObject languageJSON = formData.getJSONObject( "useForeignLanguage" );
            if ( ( languageJSON != null ) && !( languageJSON.isNullObject() ) ) {
                this.useLanguage = languageJSON.getString( "useLanguage" );
                this.useForeignLanguage = true;
            } else {
                this.useLanguage = null;
                this.useForeignLanguage = false;
            }
            save();
            return super.configure( req, formData );
        }

        public String getUseLanguage() {
            return this.useLanguage;
        }

        public boolean getUseForeignLanguage() {
            return this.useForeignLanguage;
        }

        //...
    }
}
```

The config itself gets saved fine in an xml, which is loaded everytime the configuration is saved, so I guess the problem lies within loading and filling the form modules:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<bar.foo.testing.HelloWorldBuilder_-Descriptor plugin="YetAnotherPluginTest@1.0-SNAPSHOT">
  <useForeignLanguage>true</useForeignLanguage>
  <useLanguage>jp</useLanguage>
</bar.foo.testing.HelloWorldBuilder_-Descriptor>
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the jelly fixed the problem:

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define" xmlns:l="/lib/layout" xmlns:t="/lib/hudson"
  xmlns:f="/lib/form">

  <f:section title="Hello World Builder">
    <f:optionalBlock name="useForeignLanguage" title="Use foreign language" checked="${instance.useForeignLanguage}">
      <f:entry title="Language to use" field="useLanguage" description="Check if we should say hello in another language">
          <f:entry>
            <f:radio name="useLanguage" title="French" value="fr" checked="${instance.useLanguage == 'fr'}" />
          </f:entry>
          <f:entry>
            <f:radio name="useLanguage" title="Japanese" value="jp" checked="${instance.useLanguage == 'jp'}" />
          </f:entry>
      </f:entry>
    </f:optionalBlock>
  </f:section>

</j:jelly>
```

Comment: I would like to complement a few things from this example. First, instead of descriptor everthing was moved to the instance class, in this case it would be "HelloWorldBuilder". Aditionally in order for verify properties like "instance.useForeignLanguage" is necessary on the descriptor to override the configure method and call the method save() , just like it has been done in the initial question.